# How to lock Windows 7 into a single program with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, fullscreen, kiosk

I have been working on an app in Visual Studio 2015 (C++). It's a kiosk app for my school's tech support. Basically, it's a support site that will run in a kiosk. I need to figure out how to lock windows so it only runs that program. It would also be helpful to run the program in fullscreen mode. Keep in mind that all of the kiosks run Windows 7.

Comment: Windows 7 has a "kiosk mode". You should be able to use that to do what you want.

Comment: @ChrisF - no it really doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually switched from C++ to C#, so I'm gonna explain my answer with C#.

I used a keyboard hook library to capture keyboard input and block all non-letter/number input so alt-f4, alt-tab etc. would not work. I then determined a closing sequence of characters using another keyboard hook (LWin+C+Home+F12+PrtSc).

As for Ctrl-Alt-Del, that cannot be disabled (as far as I know) because it is a system function, so I just left that as it is.

I also got the bounds of the screen and set the size of the window to the maximum screen size at application launch, as well as whenever the app is resized or moved. This essentially makes it so the app covers the task bar, and the bar with the close and minimize buttons is also covered, but if someone found a way to move it it would immediately go back to it's full size.

I also set up autologin as was detailed in a previous answer, but I just didn't do it through code.

Answer (score 5):

Set registry key

```
HKCU SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
Shell="c:\path\to\whatever.exe"
```

Disallow task manager via security of taskmgr.exe (add a deny read + deny execute to the binary)

Set autologn:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
DefaultUserName = whatever
DefaultPassword = whatever
```

Have a boot disk handy. The only way to reverse this is to boot the boot disk and undo one of the steps after mounting the appropriate hive.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your program with main window in full screen mode and popup:

```
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE|WS_EX_APPWINDOW|WS_EX_TOPMOST,
                    lpClsName,
                    "MDI Project under Visual C++ WINAPI",
                    WS_BORDER|WS_POPUP,
                    ...);// add the remaining parameters
```

and find taskmgr.exe and hide it and start menu button and hide them also:

```
hTaskBar = ::FindWindow  ("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
hStart   = ::FindWindowEx(GetDesktopWindow(), NULL, "Button", "Start");         
ShowWindow(hTaskBar, SW_HIDE);
ShowWindow(hStart, SW_HIDE);
```

so your program looks like easycafe or handycafe